# Change li font in ul?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I wanted to change the font of all the li inside my ul. How do you do this?
   HTML

```
  <ul id="answers1" class="answers">
<input type="radio" name="question1" value="a" id="question1a" class="question1a"><label for="question1a"> Answer 1 </label>
```

Jsfiddle link:   http://jsfiddle.net/cfr4o2wm/

Comment: theres no `li` in your example, and you can't put an `input` or any other element inside a `ul` its invalid

Comment: As implied by jmore009: *first*, you put an `<li>` inside your `<ul>`, *then* you can style it/them. [JS Fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/cfr4o2wm/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/cfr4o2wm/1/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML was malformed and you were missing the `<li>` tag (as the others mentioned). That's why your styling wasn't being applied.

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4s2u6sqn/2/

Note: With JSFiddle, in order to use an external stylesheet (like the Roboto font one you are using), you have to add it as an "External Resource" on the left side. You can't include a `<head>` tag in the HTML content of a fiddle; it's already inserted into the output.